# why QEventLoop made segmentation fault in qt creator application?

Tags: c++, qt, async-await

I have Qt application. I have a serial port to send and receive data.When i write sth to my device on serial port, I will receive answer.My serial port class is in a thread and run in background to listen the device. this is my code:

```
    #include "portserial.h"
///!
//! \brief PortSerial::PortSerial
//! \param port the port number or address
//! \param dev connected seprately for each device
//!
PortSerial::PortSerial(QString port, int dev)
{
    printErrors("PortSerial","start fn");
    devid=dev;
    if(!openport(port))
    {
        printErrors("PortSerial","Port:"+port+" can not open.");
    }
    moveToThread(&t);
    connect(&t,SIGNAL(started()),this,SLOT(readserialport()));
    t.start();

}

//!
//! \brief PortSerial::writeData with qbyte array
//! \param ba
//!
void PortSerial::writeData(QByteArray ba)
{
    printErrors("writeData","start fn");
    serialport.write(ba);

    }

//!
//! \brief PortSerial::readserialport
//!
void PortSerial::readserialport()
{
printErrors("readserialport","start fn");
    while (1) {
        if(serialport.waitForReadyRead(100))
        {
            printErrors("readserialport","the queue is clean");
            printErrors("readserialport","wait for read data from sensor");
            QByteArray responseData=serialport.readAll();
            while (serialport.waitForReadyRead(100)) {
                responseData+=serialport.readAll();
            }
            printErrors("readserialport","read:"+responseData.toHex()+"\n devid : "+devid);
            emit readyread(responseData,devid);


        }
    }
}
```

when data ready from device my signal emit and fill my Queue in fp class.fp class is a class between my UI(QML) and serial port class.when my ui send data to fp class , the command send to serial port class . My problem is here, I need to wait for device response.so I create a wait function to wait for firing signal from serial port. If user click on cancel button my waiting function send me SEGMENTATION FAULT. but if user doesn't click cancel, all of them work well.

```
int FP::WaitProccessorForResult(int milisecond)
{
//ui_interface()->cancelUIOperation()    => if true means cancel button pressed
    printErrors("WaitProccessorForResult","in waiting.....");
    int rv=0;int i=0;

    //ui_interface()->setCancelUIOperation(false);
    QEventLoop loop;
        QTimer timer;
        //timer.setSingleShot(true);
    //if device answer quit the loop
        connect( this,SIGNAL(fullQueue()), &loop,SLOT(quit()) );
  //if user cancel quit the loop
        connect(ui_interface(),SIGNAL(CancelUIOperationChanged()),&loop,SLOT(quit()));
    //if timer finished quit the loop
        connect( &timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &loop, SLOT(quit()) );
    timer.start(milisecond);
    loop.exec();

    if(timer.isActive())
        qDebug("===============QEventLoop================encrypted");
    else
        qDebug("+++++++++++++++QEventLoop++++++++++++++++timeout");
//    for( i=0;i<milisecond;)
//    {
//        i=i+1000;

//        QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents);

//        qDebug()<<i;
//        if(myque.length()>0 || ui_interface()->cancelUIOperation())
//        {
//            i=milisecond;
//            break;
//        }

//    }

    if(ui_interface()->cancelUIOperation())
    {
        myque.clear();
        printErrors("WaitProccessorForResult"," in CancelUIOperation:"+ui_interface()->cancelUIOperation());
        ui_interface()->setCancelUIOperation(false);
        rv=cancelByUser;
        //FPCancel();
    }
    return rv;
}
```

before `QEVENTLOOP` i used `QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents);` but segmentation fault occured again. some one told me to use `QEVENTLOOP` but there had not changed.

Comment: Don'tuse a custom event loop but signals and slots to wait for data. Spinning an event loop inside another one is never as good idea (and will lead to crashes now and then as you can see)

Comment: @chehrlic, thanx. so what to use to make a waiting?

Comment: Don't wait but use signals and slots to get the result.